# Spring Authorization Server not working with context-path

Tags: spring, spring-security-oauth2

I have an autherization server which built with Spring 1.5.7 and it was working fine. Now when I tried to move to Spring 2 this is working. I have also followed all the steps of https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ with no luck. Problem is that when I use it without context-path it works fine like http://localhost:8080/oauth/token but when I use a context path it is not able to authenticate like http://localhost:8080/auth/oauth/token . This was working in the older version of Spring boot i.e. 1.5.7 but with Spring boot 2.1.8 which i tried it is not working. Any help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the problem. With Spring 2 server.context-path is depricated and server.servlet.context-path is the way forward. Once I used server.servlet.context-path everything worked fine

Comment: A link reference to the documentation can be useful.